# How to copy objects managed by Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, apache-commons-beanutils

I want to copy an object into another (its properties). This object is
managed by Hibernate and has lazy collections. PropertyUtils.copyProperties()
throws lazy exception.

Is there any way?

PS: I do not want to [unproxy](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=939454) my object since I don't own it (its in another jar)

Answer (score 0):

You can call Hibernate.initialize() on every lazy collectio of your original object before copying. Obviously, it would not work outside of a transaction, if yor object is detached from the Hibernate session. So, you have to initialize your lazy collections early enough.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but as I say I do not want to unproxy the objects (I do not have access to hibernate in my jar)

Comment: What exception are you getting exactly? Is it org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException? If it is, it means that the transaction is already done and the object is detached from the Hibernate session.

Comment: Yes it is LazyInitializationException. But I cannot merge the entity because I do not have access to the Hibernate session. Is there any way to copy the proxies references of the entity?

Comment: I do not believe this is possible. I don't believe you can take an object with proxy references detached from one Hibernate session and attach it to another. You have to negotiate with whoever provides you the service layer functionality to return fully flushed out objects rather than the ones with the proxies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will wait until some more confirmations of you answer and I will close the ticket.